# singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates - Non Linear Regression

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

so I'm new to data science using R and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. using the data set:

| rocketBurn | Oxygen Consumed | Hydrogen Used | Trajectory | Thrust |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 20000 | 30000 | 0 | 500000 |
| 40 | 40000 | 60000 | 0 | 525000 |
| 60 | 60000 | 90000 | 0 | 551250 |
| 80 | 80000 | 120000 | 4 | 578813 |
| 100 | 100000 | 150000 | 8 | 593283 |
| 120 | 120000 | 180000 | 12 | 593283 |
| 140 | 140000 | 210000 | 16 | 593283 |
| 160 | 160000 | 240000 | 20 | 593283 |
| 180 | 180000 | 270000 | 24 | 593283 |
| 200 | 200000 | 300000 | 28 | 593283 |
| 220 | 220000 | 330000 | 32 | 593283 |
| 240 | 240000 | 360000 | 36 | 593283 |
| 260 | 260000 | 390000 | 40 | 593283 |
| 280 | 280000 | 420000 | 44 | 593283 |
| 300 | 300000 | 450000 | 46 | 593283 |
| 320 | 320000 | 480000 | 46 | 593283 |

I was able to create the linear regression model using the lm() formula in R, when I try to use the nls formula I am recieing the following error message

```html
nlrModel <- nls(Trajectory ~ Oxygen.Consumed + Thrust,data = df,start = c(a=0,b=0,c=0))
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts, scaleOffset = scOff, nDcentral = nDcntr) : 
 singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

After some googling I believe the error is due to the start parms, however, I don't know how to get the correct start parm. Any help on how to get this model to work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let us start with, What is the equation you are trying to fit?  Since "Oxygen" + "Thrust"  is not a realistic formula to equal "Trajectory".

Comment: this is the linear model I created, the ask was to create a model using these variables. if I shouldn't be using it the way I am can you please explain why and what I should do?

Comment: Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.1001 -0.3476  0.3379  1.0271  1.8617 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      2.263e+01  1.176e+01   1.925   0.0764 .  
Oxygen.Consumed  1.908e-04  6.502e-06  29.344 2.88e-13 ***
Thrust          -5.662e-05  2.156e-05  -2.626   0.0209 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.708 on 13 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9914, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9901 
F-statistic: 749.2 on 2 and 13 DF,  p-value: 3.755e-14

Comment: Call:
lm(formula = Trajectory ~ Oxygen.Consumed + Thrust, data = df)

Comment: If you want to a linear module such as a*Oxygen* + b*Thrust* + c then  use the `lm()` function.  **Only** when your equation is non-linear should you consider using `nls()` [nonlinear least squares] function!! Since you were able to obtain a result with `lm` I am not understanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the formula in the nls model is wrong.  lm and nls do not use the same formula notation. In lm for a model with no interactions the independent variables are listed separated by plus signs whereas in nls the formula includes the coefficients.  For example, this describes the same model in lm and nls.

```
lm(Trajectory ~ Oxygen.Consumed + Thrust, df)

st <- list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)
nls(Trajectory ~ a + b * Oxygen.Consumed + c * Thrust, df, start = st)
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

```
df <- 
structure(list(rocketBurn = c(20L, 40L, 60L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 
140L, 160L, 180L, 200L, 220L, 240L, 260L, 280L, 300L, 320L), 
    Oxygen.Consumed = c(20000L, 40000L, 60000L, 80000L, 100000L, 
    120000L, 140000L, 160000L, 180000L, 200000L, 220000L, 240000L, 
    260000L, 280000L, 300000L, 320000L), Hydrogen.Used = c(30000L, 
    60000L, 90000L, 120000L, 150000L, 180000L, 210000L, 240000L, 
    270000L, 300000L, 330000L, 360000L, 390000L, 420000L, 450000L, 
    480000L), Trajectory = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 20L, 
    24L, 28L, 32L, 36L, 40L, 44L, 46L, 46L), Thrust = c(500000L, 
    525000L, 551250L, 578813L, 593283L, 593283L, 593283L, 593283L, 
    593283L, 593283L, 593283L, 593283L, 593283L, 593283L, 593283L, 
    593283L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```